# how to post an object using rest template and accept the response

Tags: spring

I am trying to call a rest endpoint by passing an object and get the response. It is working in postman.
Here is my url: https://test.ap.com/rest/user/create

type:post

body:{
    "gender":"MALE",
    "weight":965.0,
    "height":40.0,
    "name":"testuser"
    }

and the response is

{
"id":"1234",
"token":"1234%"
}

when I tried in a code I am getting  httpclienterrorexception:401  error

Here is my code:

```
public void createAccount(){

UserData userData = new UserData();
userData.setGender("MALE");
userData.setWeight(965.0);
userData.setHeight(40.0);
userData.setName("test1");

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders(); 
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<UserData> requestEntity  = new HttpEntity<UserData>(userData,headers);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<ResponseUser> entity= restTemplate.exchange(userRegUrl,HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, ResponseUser.class);

}
```

ResponseUser class:

public class ResponseUSer {

```
private String id;
private String token;

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}

public String getSId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id= id;
}
```

why my code is getting 401 error. how to post an object and consume the response.

Comment: Take a look in Authorization header. Http status 401 is for Unauthorized Access.

Comment: I specified content type as json. Did I miss anything in the header part?

Comment: Yes you did - authorization

Comment: can somebody help me to fix this issue. what other data I need to add ?